# how to store query string value in an array using .net

Tags: arrays, string, vb.net-2010, querystringparameter

am using current page aspx as url.am passing query string in my page url.my code used to split the query string and write in the screen. am writing code in page load method.

```
my code
------
 Dim strarr() As String
    Dim key
    For Each key In Request.QueryString
        Response.Write(key & ": " & Request.QueryString(key) & "<BR>")

    Next

output
------
http://localhost:54592/vicidial_project/Default.aspx?a=1&b=2(in run time am passing query string to that url)

a:1
b:2

the query string values are displayed in the screen like above.

my question
-----------
i want to store that query string value into an array . am using the code like this

code
-----
 Dim strarr() As String
    Dim key
    For Each key In Request.QueryString
        Response.Write(key & ": " & Request.QueryString(key) & "<BR>")
       strarr = key & ": " & Request.QueryString(key)

    Next

error
-----
 am getting error in this line
 strarr = key & ": " & Request.QueryString(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you declare key as a String?  You could have done it so:

```
For Each key as String in Request.QueryString
   ...
Next
```

Comment: am getting error like" type string can't be converted in to 1-dimenssional array of string